# Make monit mail-format send top as well

Tags: monit

I'm using `monit` to monitor some services. However, I want to get an email which includes the output from `top` when this happens. Is there some way to get this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if you can get it from the mail-format (which would be pretty nice) but they have the following example in the [monit wiki](https://mmonit.com/wiki/Monit/ConfigurationExamples#topsnap):

```
check file myfile with path /tmp/foo.bar if changed timestamp then
   exec "/bin/bash -c 'top -bn1 | mail -s top admin@foo.bar'"
```