# how to send top snapshot when monit loadavg matched

Tags: monit

I am getting occasional resource limit (loadavg) alerts from monit in the middle of the night.  The server seems to recover fine, but I'd love to know what's going on right at that time.

The (default) monit alert email includes a "description", but that just indicates that the loadavg (1min) or (5min) hit my threshold.

How can I setup this specific alert to include something like a 'top' snapshot so I can see the top 10-20 procs and figure out what's actually using all the resources?

I found this: [stackoverflow-31513996](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31513996/make-monit-mail-format-send-top-as-well), but I don't want to generate additional alerts, I just want additional info in the alert.  Or should I somehow disable the alert on this test and enable an 'exec' like this link suggests???

Monit v5.14 on CentOS 7.

Answer (score 0):

There is no possibility (yet) to customize the message content with custom values when using built-in alerts. You have to disable the alert and use a custom script as in the link you suggest.